# Buffer events, start new group 1 second after the last event from previous group

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I am on Android and I created an `Observable` of touch downs. And I would like to buffer them as long as new events are coming within a second. When a second elapsed from the last touch down emission, I want to create a list of all collected events and emit it, and start a new collection.

I have 2 snippets of code which work but they either don't seem too reactive (#1) or unnecessarily complex (#2). Here they are:

1. I use the `buffer(Func0<? extends Observable<? extends TClosing>> bufferClosingSelector)` overload - when the returned selector emits an item, it means a second elapsed from the last source emission and the buffer can be emitted.
2. The `Obserbable` the selector function returns is a `PublishSubject` so that I can decide when to push emissions to it.
3. There exists a `Runnable` task which pushes new emissions to the closing subject. This task is scheduled (via an Android Handler) to run a second after the currently processed source touch down emission happened. When a new source emission of a new touch down happens afterwards within a second, the task is cancelled, and a new one is scheduled again after a second.

Here is the relevant Android code:

```
    final PublishSubject<MotionEvent> touchPublishSubject = PublishSubject.create();

    final ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    viewGroup.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            touchPublishSubject.onNext(event);

            return true;
        }
    });

    final PublishSubject<Object> windowClosePublishSubject = PublishSubject.create();
    final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "will emit closing item");
            windowClosePublishSubject.onNext("now!");
        }
    };

    ViewObservable
            .bindView(viewGroup, touchPublishSubject)
            .filter(new Func1<MotionEvent, Boolean>() {

                @Override
                public Boolean call(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    return motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
                }
            })
            .doOnNext(new Action1<MotionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void call(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    // restart the timer
                    Log.d(TAG, "cancelling closing");
                    handler.removeCallbacks(r);
                    Log.d(TAG, "scheduling closing");
                    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000L);

                    // show the touch
                    Log.d(TAG, motionEvent.toString());
                }
            })
            .buffer(new Func0<Observable<?>>() {

                @Override
                public Observable<?> call() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "creating buffer closing selector");
                    return windowClosePublishSubject
                            .doOnNext(new Action1<Object>() {

                                @Override
                                public void call(Object o) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "emitting closing item '" + o + "'");
                                }
                            });
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new Action1<List<MotionEvent>>() {

                @Override
                public void call(List<MotionEvent> motionEvents) {
                    // show number of touch downs
                    Log.d(TAG, "got " + motionEvents.size() + " touch downs");
                }
            });
```

I don't fancy the usage of `Handler` and all that in this solution, so I looked further.

The second snippet (the touchPublishSubject and the touch listener are exactly the same):

1. I reuse the touch down generating `touchPublishSubject` as the window closing observable, debouncing it first with a 1 sec timeout
2. Apparently, as the debouncing happens on `Scheduler.computation()`, it moves observing to the same scheduler and I need to use `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` - I find it a bit strange that the nested `Observable`'s scheduler, which only closes the buffer windows,
   promotes the whole chain to happen in its scheduler as well

The code:

```
    final PublishSubject<MotionEvent> touchPublishSubject = PublishSubject.create();

    final ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    viewGroup.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            touchPublishSubject.onNext(event);

            return true;
        }
    });

    ViewObservable
            .bindView(viewGroup, touchPublishSubject)
            .filter(new Func1<MotionEvent, Boolean>() {

                @Override
                public Boolean call(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    return motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
                }
            })
            .doOnNext(new Action1<MotionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void call(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    // show the touch
                    Log.d(TAG, motionEvent.toString());
                }
            })
            .buffer(new Func0<Observable<?>>() {

                @Override
                public Observable<?> call() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "creating buffer closing selector");
                    return touchPublishSubject
                            .debounce(1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .doOnNext(new Action1<Object>() {

                                @Override
                                public void call(Object o) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "emitting closing item '" + o + "'");
                                }
                            });
                }
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<List<MotionEvent>>() {

                @Override
                public void call(List<MotionEvent> motionEvents) {
                    // show number of touch downs
                    Log.d(TAG, "got " + motionEvents.size() + " touch downs");
                }
            });
```

This code works and I like it better than the first one, feels more like it should be done with Rx. But it is complex because of the nested `Observable` and the brain gymnastics necessary to get it. Is there a `buffer` overload I'm missing to automatically do the same (i.e. close its window after the last emission is 1 sec old)?

**Edit**: one of the comments made me aware of a presentation by Ben Christensen, and then I found this: https://blog.kaush.co/2015/01/05/debouncedbuffer-with-rxjava/, which links to a few implementation of the problem. Seems like a pretty common requirement, would be nice to have a built-in operator for this. Anyways, I would consider the solution presented in these other sources and here to be canon for this type of problems.

Comment: I think there was something similar in Ben Christensen's QConSF presentation on slide 100: https://speakerdeck.com/benjchristensen/reactive-programming-with-rx-at-qconsf-2014

Comment: This is interesting, this is almost exactly what I did. He just used the `publish().refCount()` calls for some reason, which my code doesn't seem to require, or at least it works without them. So, for the time being I will consider this _the_ way to do it.

Comment: I understand now. I think that for my code, it doesn't matter if publish() and refCount() are called as I do it in onCreate on Android, and the subscribers are all wired before the events start coming.